Integrate Elastic APM to Vercel Serverless Functions
I tried to integrate my NextJS application with an Elastic APM. The main idea is I initiate apm object in every API request, so the request span will collected and will be sent to Elastic APM. It's working on the local development and docker deployment, but when I deploy it to Vercel and the APIs became serverless function, the elastic APM never receive any data. Here's the last line of the serverless function log:
{
    "log.level": "debug",
    "@timestamp": "2024-04-18T08:45:47.694Z",
    "log.logger": "elastic-apm-node",
    "ecs.version": "8.10.0",
    "message": "sending span {\"span\":\"08ffc510e6b2a80d\",\"parent\":\"42b99f30dbacb024\",\"trace\":\"f03e53c3d6846a888f8f69c753b3aa81\",\"name\":\"POST xxxx.ingest.sentry.io\",\"type\":\"external\"}"
}

I have this apm.ts file for initiating elastic-apm-node
import apm from 'elastic-apm-node';

if (!apm.isStarted()) {
    apm.start({
        // config needed
    });
}

export default apm;

and this code is called on apiHandler.ts
apm.setUserContext({
    email: session.user.email,
    id: session.user.id,
});
apm.setCustomContext({});

With that simple config, I can found my local PC on the APM, but not when I hosted the app on Vercel.
development app added on APM
